# moving files based on matching timestamp in filename VBscript

Tags: vbscript

So I need a bit of help, I am still new at vbscript. I have a directory with over 100 files of different types, but would like to only move the files with the correct timestamp to another directory.

The naming convention of the files are as follows: stuff-11012013-042567.txt, I would like to move only files with matching timestamps.

I have started my script as follows but I am stuck to how I would find and match the particular string in the filename, and would I have to set the matching results to variable in order to move all files at once?

```
'Create file object system and declare to variable
 Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Get source and destination folders, set source and destination folder paths to variables
Set sfldr=objFSO.getFolder("in")
Set dfldr=objFSO.getFolder("out")

'Check to see if source folder Exists
If objFSO.FolderExists("in\") Then

   'Check to see if there are existing files on destination folder
   If dFldr.files.count = 0 Then

     If sfldr.files.count < 6 then
        msgbox("Need more files!")
     ElseIf sfldr.files.count > 6 then
        msgbox("Too many files, please double check for consistency")
     Else

         'Enter loop to move all files from source directory to destination directory
          for each file in sfldr.files
              objFSO.MoveFile "in\*", "out"
          Next
     End If
  Else
    msgbox("Files already Exists on Destination Folder. Please Check files!")
  End If
Else
    msgbox("Source path does not exist")
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `For` loop, you will need to check the name of each file and decide what to do with it.

If the timestamp is always in the same position in the file name, you can use the `Mid()` function. If the position varies, you can use `Instr()`.